# Lag / Screen Freezes when hiding Status Bar dynamically in a Scroll View (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift3, statusbar

I am currently using a `Scroll View` with different pages. I am aiming to hide the `Status Bar` on one specific page. There is a really annoying **lag** and the **screen freezes** every time the `Status Bar` is about to reappear/disappear.

This is my approach:

First of all I defined two variables

```
private var currentPage = 0

private var isStatusBarPreferablyHidden = true
```

I then used two functions from the Scroll View Delegate to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` when the user swipes to the first page

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentScrollPosition : CGFloat = self.navigation.contentOffset.x / self.navigation.frame.size.width
    currentPage = lroundf(Float(currentScrollPosition))
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if currentPage == 0 {

        isStatusBarPreferablyHidden = true
    } else {

        isStatusBarPreferablyHidden = false
    }

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Finally I overrode the Status Bar Functions to update the appearance of the Status Bar.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {

    return isStatusBarPreferablyHidden
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {

    return UIStatusBarAnimation.none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`.
Try:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentScrollPosition : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = lroundf(Float(currentScrollPosition))
    if page != currentPage {
        currentPage = page
        if currentPage == 0 {
            isStatusBarPreferablyHidden = true
        } else {
            isStatusBarPreferablyHidden = false
        }
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not change anything at all! Same Lag, not even working appropriately. I am sorry but this answer does not solve anything -.-

Comment: @Devapploper What do you mean by lag. I test your code. It goes well after  i change to `scrollViewWillBeginDragging `.

Comment: Whenever the statusbar is about to change, the scroll view and all other things freeze for about 1/2 Sesond. This happens independently from the used delegate method

Comment: @Devapploper See if my solution meets your requirements.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and your code works, such as mine does. But that is not the point. The reason I posted this question, is that the transition from the view with Status Bar to the view without the status bar causes the screen to freeze for a bit. This answer does not solve the problem, but I am super thankful for your effort and help! :)